# use proxy setup true false

Tags: go

I want to create simple function with option true/false for use proxy.
this is my actual code :

```
var torProxy string = "socks5://127.0.0.1:9050"

func getPage(webUrl string, useProxy bool) {
    torProxyUrl, err := url.Parse(torProxy)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error parsing Tor proxy URL:", torProxy, ".", err)
    }

    transport := &http.Transport{
        DisableKeepAlives: true,
    }
    torTransport := &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(torProxyUrl)}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport, Timeout: time.Second * 5}
    if useProxy {
        client = &http.Client{Transport: torTransport, Timeout: time.Second * 5}
    }

    // Make request
    resp, err := client.Get(webUrl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error making GET request.", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Read response
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error reading body of response.", err)
    }
    log.Println(string(body))
    log.Println("Return status code:", resp.StatusCode)
}

func main() {
    getPage("getPage", false)
}
```

When i execute my code return this error : `2018/04/19 08:28:25 Error making GET request.Get getPage: unsupported protocol scheme ""
exit status 1` where i wrong ?

Comment: `getPage("getPage", false)`:  you are passing `"getPage"` as `webUrl` which is not a valid url.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an invalid URL in your call. Change

```
func main() {
    getPage("getPage", false)
}
```

to

```
func main() {
    const urlStr = 'https://stackoverflow.com' // Or whatever URL
    getPage(urlStr, false)
}
```